# Simple way of encrypting string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption

I want to send information between my client and NodeJS server.  I need a *simple* way of encrypting messages from the client.

I've tried:
http://javascript.about.com/library/blencrypt.htm

but I need something simpler

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/ ?

Very simple to use,

```
var sensitiveInfo = "yodawgpasswords";
var encryptedInfo = sjcl.encrypt("password", sensitiveInfo);
var decryptedInfo = sjcl.decrypt("password", encryptedInfo);
```

Comment: The issue here is that the encryption key is symmetric. The server and client need to agree on the password. If it is set by the server and sent over in the page, an eavesdropper on the network would be able to see it and then decrypt the message on submit. The commenter on the question is correct. Use HTTPS/TLS if the session needs security.

Comment: Thanks, I don't need anything too complex as it's just a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTTPS Node.js Module.

Doc: http://nodejs.org/api/https.html